# How to apply the universal quantifier in Prolog?

Tags: prolog

Suppose you have a disease diagnosis Prolog program that starts with many relations between diseases and symptons:

```
causes_of(symptom1, Disease) :-
    Disease = disease1;
    Disease = disease2.
causes_of(symptom2, Disease) :-
    Disease = disease2;
    Disease = disease3.
causes_of(symptom3, Disease) :-
    Disease = disease4.

has_symptom(person1, symptom1).
has_symptom(person1, symptom2).
```

How can I create a rule with the head 'has_disease(Person, Disease)' that will return true if the person has all the symptoms from that disease? Using the example above the following would a sample output:

```
has_disease(person1, Disease).
   Disease = disease2.
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, there is probably a much simpler way to do this, as my Prolog skills are minor at best.

```
has_disease(Person, Disease) :- atom(Disease),
    findall(Symptom, has_symptom(Person, Symptom), PersonSymptoms),
    findall(DSymptom, causes_of(DSymptom, Disease), DiseaseSymptoms),
    subset(DiseaseSymptoms, PersonSymptoms).

has_diseases(Person, Diseases) :-
    findall(Disease, (causes_of(_, Disease), has_disease(Person, Disease)), DiseaseList),
    setof(Disease, member(Disease, DiseaseList), Diseases).
```

To be called as follows:

```
?- has_diseases(person1, D).
D = [disease1, disease2, disease3].
```

The [`findall/3`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=findall%2f3) predicate is used first to find all symptoms a person has, then again to find all symptoms a disease has, then a quick check to see if the disease's symptoms are a subset of the person's.

The way I have written the `has_disease/2` predicate prevents it from giving a list of diseases.  So I created `has_diseases/2`, which performs another `findall` on any disease it can find, using `has_disease/2` as the check.  A [`setof/3`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=setof%2f3) call is used last to get unique results on the disease list and order it for convenience.

NB. The [`atom/1`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=atom%2f1) on the `has_disease/2` primitive is just to ensure a variable is not passed in for `Disease`, as it does not work in that case, at least not for me.

Answer (score 1):

You will need a way to query all symptoms, e.g. with `findall(S,cause_of(S,disease),SS)`, where `SS` will be the list of symptoms for this disease.

Comment: Could give an example of how I would do this?